# Data normalization in GraphQL query

Tags: graphql, database-normalization

I'm using GraphQL to query a database that has two data types: `User` and `Group`.

Groups have a field `users` which is an array of `User` objects which are in that group.  I have one field at root named `groups` which returns an array of all of my groups.

A typical query might look something like this:

```
{
    groups {
        id,
        name,
        users {
            id,
            name,
            address,
            email,
            phone,
            attitude,
            job,
            favoriteQuote,
            favoriteColor,
            birthday
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that a lot of those users can belong to multiple groups and, seeing as `User` has a lot of fields, this can make responses quite large.

**Is there any way to get one set of fields for the first instance of an object, and a different set for every other instance in the response?**

I only need `name`, `job`, `email` etc etc once per user in the response, and just the `id` thereafter (I can do my own normalization afterwards).

*alternatively*

**Is there any way to only get `id` fields for all users in groups and return a separate array of all unique `User` objects that have been referenced in the query (which is not *all* `User` objects)?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way to get one set of fields for the first instance of an object, and a different set for every other instance in the response?

No. The same set of fields will be returned for each item in a list unless the type of the individual item is different, since a separate selection set can be specified for each type returned at runtime.

> Is there any way to only get id fields for all users in groups and return a separate array of all unique User objects that have been referenced in the query (which is not all User objects)?

You could design your schema to accommodate this. Something like

```
{
  groups {
    nodes {
      id
      name
      users {
        id
      }
    }
    uniqueUsers {
      id
      # other fields
    }
  }
}
```

Your `groups` resolver would need to handle all the normalization and return the data in the appropriate shape. However, a simpler solution might be to just invert your relationship:

```
{
  users {
    id
    name
    address
    email
    phone
    attitude
    job
    favoriteQuote
    favoriteColor
    birthday
    groups {
      id
      name
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Cool - I don't own the implementation of this, but I'm sure I could get the guys who do on-board

Answer (score 1):

### Generally - usually

... normalization ... of course ... f.e. using `apollo` and it's normalized cache.

**All records returned from API has to be the same shape.**

You can get data and render some `<MembersList/>` component using query for ids and names only (full/paginated).

Later you can render details in some `<UserProfile/>` component with own query (hook `useQuery` inside) to fetch additional data from cache/api (controllable).

### Your specific requirements - possible

### 1st option:

Usually response is of one common shape (as requested), but you can decide on resolver level what to return. This requires query structure changes that allows (API, backend) to null-ify some properties. F.e.

```
group {
    id
    name
    users {
        id
        name
        profile {
          photo
          email
          address
```

With `profile` custom json type ... you can construct users resolver to return full data only for 1st record and `null` for all following users.

### 2nd option:

You can use 2 slightly different queries in **one request**. Use aliases (see docs), in short:

```
groupWithFullMember: group ( groupId:xxx, limitUsers:1 ) {
    id
    name
    users {
        id
        name
        address
        email
        ...
    }
}

groupMembers: group ( groupId:xxx ) {
    id
    name // not required
    users {
        id
        name
    }
}
```

Group resolver can return it's child `users` ... or `users` resolver can access `limitUsers` param to limit response/modify db query.

Comment: I'm hoping to do this in a single query

Comment: Interesting - I'll have to run this by my backend guys who own the implementation